# How can I transform an object into a different object from the same base class?

Tags: java, object, polymorphism

Let's say I have a board game where players can buy the squares that they land on. I have a method in my abstract base class of Squares called this:

```
public abstract void applyLandOnAffect(Player player);
```

Then in my class of BuyableSquares I implement this method shown below:

```
@Override
 public void applyLandOnAffect(Player player){
    //Offer them the chance buy the square here.
}
```

Then if they choose to buy the square I want the object to change from a BuyableSquares() into a BoughtSquare(). The code in the BoughtSquare would handle what happens when another player lands on a bought square. But the issue is how and where I should transform it.

I was thinking this type of code:

```
this = new BoughtSquare();
```

But it's not accepted syntax.

How do I approach this?

Thanks

Comment: You can't _ever_ assign a value to `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using polymorphism to have different processing of Square instances depending on its type, my suggestion is to use **State design pattern**.

To introduce it in your application you should:

- define a new interface named e.g. `SquareState` with methods that differ depending on the square type

  ```
  public interface SquareState {
      void applyLandOnAffect(Player player);
  }
  ```
- define all square types which will implement this interface and provide the implementation of the methods from the `SquareState` interface

  ```
  public AvailableState implements SquareState {
      public void applyLandOnAffect(Player player) { // ..
      }
  }

  public BoughtState implements SquareState {
      public void applyLandOnAffect(Player player) { // ..
      }
  }
  ```
- introduce a new attribute inside the `Square` class that will store the current state of the square

  ```
  public class Square {
      private SquareState state;
      // ..
  }
  ```

Once you have done that, changing the state of the Square will be a matter of calling:

```
this.state = new BoughtSquare();
```

Comment: @cmbaxter I have done incremental editing on this answer, started with an outline, then added code snippets at the end :)

Answer (score 0):

You should just have one class called `Square` instead of having separate classes for purchased squares and unpurchased squares. Or you can extend `Square` if you plan on having other types of squares that are not purchasable. Create a boolean value in your class called `purchased` that's set to `false` by default. Then when the square is purchased you can set the value to `true`.

```
public class PurchaseableSquare extends Square
{
    private boolean purchased;

    public Square()
    {
        this.purchased = false;
    }

    public void purchaseSquare()
    {
        this.purchased = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you **can't** assign anything to `this`.

In order to achieve what you want, why not create a flag in the `BuyableSquares` class, that indicates whether or not the square is bought.

```
 public class BuyableSquares extends Squares {

     private boolean bought = false; // by default

     //...

     public void markAsBought() {
          bought = true;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you instantiate an object, you cannot change its class.

An option would that, as both classes already extend a superclass, use that as the reference to the classes so you can easily replace them. So, you store your board as a set (or list or array) of Square, each of them is a `BuyableSquare` or a `BoughtSquare`. When a `BuyableSquare` must be transformed, you replace it from your structure with the correspondent `BoughtSquare` (of course, a `BoughtSquare` constructor that takes the original `BuyableSquare` as a parameter would be advisable).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous post the the `State` pattern is best.  Setup the `Square` class with a state variable that you can switch to different states when different events happen to that square.  Then, have each state encapsulate the behaviors for what happens when a player lands on the square and it is in a particular state.  To change states, just reassign a different instance of `SquareState` to the `state` variable.  A very simple outline would look like this.

```
interface SquareState{
    void applyLandOnAffect(Player player);
}

public class Square{
  private SquareState state = new AvailabelState();
}

public AvailableState implements SquareState{
    public void applyLandOnAffect(Player player){
      ...
    }
}

public BoughtState implements SquareState{
    public void applyLandOnAffect(Player player){
      ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the examples that justify the rule prefer composition over inheritance.

In your case you have `Square` subtypes where you define the behavior. The problem is that your object can't change class, so it can't be transformed from `BuyableSquare` to `BoughtSquare`. A design based on composition would create a new interface for the square's state. So Square has a `SquareState`. The different behaviors of bought and not bought squares will be defined in different subtypes of the SquareState interface. So when somebody buys a square you just change its state. Something like:

```
public class Square {
    private SquareState state = new Buyable();
    public void buyMe() {
        this.state=new Bought();
    }
}
```